# Is there any charting lib for C++?

Tags: c++, charts

I have a C++ program that generates some data and i need to generate some charts for that data and to plot some functions.
Is there any free library available that can do that and just generate a png/jpeg(format doesn't matter)?
Google charts is not an option as i want to be able to generate charts even when offline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out http://qwt.sourceforge.net/. It's Qt-based.

Answer (score 2):

In the past there have been various implementations (C, C++, other) of a API for [Gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/). I don't know what the current status of these api's is.

Comment: Alternatively you can just generate the input and definitions files and run gnuplot as a subprocess.

Answer (score 2):

[ChartDirector for C++](http://www.advsofteng.com/cdcpp.html)

Answer (score 0):

Create some temporary input and definition files for gnuplot, and run it as a subprocess.

Answer (score 0):

ChartDirector is awsome. We used it for 7 years. But it is not free but not expensive. It is very worth to have

Answer (score 0):

If the output format doesn't matter you can use the header only [chartjs-cpp](https://github.com/efernea/chartjs-cpp) class to generate single html/jscript pages containing one or more charts (without any external dependencies).

The generated html files can be viewed in a browser both offline and online.

The API is very simple. Example:

```cpp
ChartJsCpp("chartjscpp_example.html", "60%")
    .Html("<center>")
    .Html("<h1>ChartJs Example</h1>")
    .Html("<h2>Line</h2>")
    .Chart<int>("Line", {10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80})
        .DataSet<double>("Series 1", "line", "dd6644", {5.4,3.2,3.7,8.4,1.5,6.9,4.7,3.8})
        .DataSet<double>("Series 2", "bar", "7766aa", {15.4,13.2,13.7,18.4,11.5,6.9,14.7,3.8}, "pointRadius: 0");
```